# Reference for a proof required

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am trying to prove the following claim.

"The set of poles of a meromorphic function is discrete."

The claim is used in the proof of The Second Liouville Theorem in the book of Freitag and Busam but they leave the details to the reader.

I don't know where to start with the proof of this claim, a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: It is an immediate consequenec of the definitions of isolated singularities and meromoprhic functions.

Comment: Poles are zeroes of $1/f$ which is meromorphic too so apply the theorem on zeroes

Comment: Another way to see it is if you know the definition of the Laurent Series.  The local Laurent Series at a pole has no singularities except at the pole itself, since all the fractional terms are well-defined off the pole.